# Why does Firebird preserve dependencies?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a procedure that depends on a view in my Firebird database. Today, I changed the view, and by doing so, I expected to resolve a bug in my procedure. Then I found out (after about an hour of frustration), that my procedure was still using a previous version of my view.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (granted, it's not a very real-world usage of a procedure):

```
-- Create a view
create view select_one_view as select 1 as one from rdb$database;

-- Create a procedure that selects from my view
SET TERM ^ ;

create procedure select_from_view
returns (number integer) as
begin
    select one from select_one_view into :number;
    suspend;
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

So now I've got my procedure that depends on a view. When I execute this procedure (`execute procedure select_from_view`), it returns 1, as expected.

Now let's alter the view:

```
alter view select_one_view as select 2 as one from rdb$database;
```

At this point, I would expect my procedure to return 2. Instead, it returns 1.

As a sanity check, I tried doing the same thing in SQL Server, but it worked as I expected, returning 2 after I altered my view.

Why in the world would I want this to happen? Am I expected to manually alter every procedure/trigger that depends on my view? It seems as if this behavior would only serve to create unnoticed problems.

P.S. I've tried this with versions V2.5.2.26539 and V2.5.2.26540.

Comment: if you disconnect all attachments of this database and reconnects, does it still returns the wrong value?

Comment: Oh man! Can't believe I didn't try that. Disconnecting fixed the problem entirely. Would you add that as an answer?

Comment: @AdrianodosSantosFernandes Please add the answer to the question and explain why does it work this way. Im really curious.

Comment: Thanks @RayZane, with this question you pointed out a behaviour I always hate in Firebird! I hope that someone could find a way to disable it!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is something related with Firebird's file system cache.

You can check this parameters:

at the database level:
Forced writes

in the firebird.conf:
MaxUnflushedWrites
MaxUnflushedWriteTime

Comment: Would these settings make is so that changes would take effect immediately (without reconnecting)?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the metadata cache. You may need to disconnect all attachments to the database and reconnect. This applies to SuperServer mode, Classic and SuperClassic mode don't share caches across attachments.